# Does fluid-framework support transactions?

Tags: fluid-framework

For example, in FluidFramework/examples/data-objects/badge/src/BadgeClient.tsx:

```
    const changeSelectedOption = (newItem: IBadgeType): void => {
        if (newItem.key !== model.currentCell.get().key) {
            const len = model.historySequence.getItemCount();
            model.historySequence.insert(len, [
                {
                    value: newItem,
                    timestamp: new Date(),
                },
            ]);
            model.currentCell.set(newItem);
        }
    };
```

Does the history-insertion op always succeed/fail together with the cell-setting op?

Comment: The local state change is likely to be atomic. But say the two ops are sent through network and one of them fails to arrive at the server, then what will happen to other clients?

Answer (score 2):

Fluid does not support transactions in the traditional sense, but Fluid does have "Group Ops." These can be created using the [orderSequentially](https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/blob/9c625d58b424204defae21cd0cec77803e291770/packages/runtime/runtime-definitions/src/dataStoreContext.ts#L73) api on the ContainerRuntime. Some DDS have a wrapper around this container level API.

Group Ops allow you to pack a group of [operations](https://fluidframework.com/docs/concepts/architecture/#fluid-service) into one message, so that the Fluid ordering service adds those ops to the [Total Order Broadcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_broadcast) in order.

Ops can only be grouped within one container because that is the boundary of the total order broadcast. Ops can be grouped across DDS within one container. This is still different than a transaction because we don't guarantee roll back of the earlier ops in the event that a later op is invalid.

You can see an example in the [Sequence DDS](https://fluidframework.com/apis/sequence/).

Below, we'll submit two ops for "hello" and "world" in one group op, ensuring that helloworld will be submitted all at once with no interleaving input.

```js
const op1 = {
    pos: 0,
    seg: "hello",
    type: MergeTreeDeltaType.INSERT,
}

const op2 = {
    pos: 5,
    seg: "world"
    type: MergeTreeDeltaType.INSERT,
}

const groupOp = {
    ops: [op1, op2],
    type: MergeTreeDeltaType.GROUP,
}

sharedString.groupOperation(groupOp);
```

The [ProseMirror fluid object](https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/tree/main/examples/data-objects/prosemirror) has more in depth code

Comment: Thanks sam! One addtional question: it looks groupOperation() only applies to the same shared sequence. Does it mean it is not possible to force 2 different objects to change transactionally? Or maybe I can modify the server to enable the feature?

Comment: You can group ops within one container, so they can affect multiple DDS within that container. Modified answer to address follow up questions.

Answer (score 2):

Not transactions but it does support batches. Batches guarantee no other operations will be interleaved between the ops in the batch. You can create a batch by using the [orderSequentially](https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/blob/9c625d58b424204defae21cd0cec77803e291770/packages/runtime/runtime-definitions/src/dataStoreContext.ts#L73) Api